# Login on Central Management Console (Business Objects) edge edition

Tags: business-objects

What's the default username and password for SAP BO CMC and BI Launch pad? I installed the trial version of SAP BusinessObjects BI Platform 4 edge edition. While installation it didn't ask for this credential to set.

Answer (score 0):

The user name for the administrator account is simply `administrator`. BI4 and previous versions always asked to provide a password during the installation, although you could leave it black in previous version. So you should have specified a password while installing (twice even, for verification purposes).

Just to be on the safe side: if you're unable to log on, always make sure that you've selected Enterprise` as type of authentication.

If you cannot remember the password, you can reset it, which involves direct manipulation of the CMS repository database. Have a look at SAP note *[1679970](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1679970) - How to reset the Administrator password in Business Intelligence Platform 4.0* which describes the steps involved (you'll need a support account to view the note).

Comment: Link is no longer available.

Comment: @Dracontis Just tested this, and the link works just fine.

Comment: @Kriftof I've received Require Authorization message when I open the link.

Comment: @Dracontis That doesn't mean the link is not available. And as I mentioned in the answer: "you'll need a support account to view the note". If you don't have an S-ID with SAP Support, you won't be able to access the link.

Comment: Ah, sorry then. But still link is quite useless, if you can't get access directly.

Answer (score 0):

user name is by default : Administrator.
Setup always asks you the password during installation so if you forgot the password than please contact sap support they are very supportive, They will handle your problems.

But if you have performed silent installation than go to config file which is being used for installation and check the string which is against the CMS Password tag .: That will be your password for central management server (CMS).